# Install Java on a debian server: broken tzdata dependency?

Tags: debian, installation, java, apt-get

I am trying to install openjdk on a debian server using SSH. My former experience tells me to use apt-get on a debian system. But i keep running into unmet dependencies. I traced it down to this:

`tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2013i-0wheezy1) but 2014a-0wheezy1 is to be installed`

What can I do to work around this issue?

For reproduction:

I tried to install openjdk with this command:
`apt-get install opendjk-6-jre`. Then I tried `apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless` and `apt-get install tzdata-java` to trace down the dependency that's broken.

`uname -a` gives me 
`2.6.32-042stab084.17 #1 SMP Fri Dec 27 17:10:20 MSK 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/errata

Should have read that much earlier. Only had to install the proposed updates.

> If you use APT to update your packages, you can install the proposed updates by adding the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> `# proposed additions for a 7 point release`
>
> `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-proposed-updates main contrib non-free`

Comment: how to add this line to the sources.list?
i'm new to linux and have a 7-days-trial root-server with just a terminal.

Comment: you could try nano, it's a text-editor for the command line: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this by grabbing the two packages needed:

http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2013i-0wheezy1_all.deb

and

http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata-java_2013i-0wheezy1_all.deb

Then installing them with dpkg -i *deb which fixes the deps so I can then re-run my apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless and it'll complete.

This has allowed me to install Jetty, which had tzdata-java as a nested dependency.

Hope it works for you.

Edit: just seen ckonig's post, perfect! Thanks for sharing that.